# La différence entre « sous peine de + infinitif » et « quitte à + infinitif »

Tags: expressions

> Ceci dit, il ne faut surtout pas en savoir trop non plus, **sous peine de** finir comme les sénateurs.
>
> = "That said, you must not stick your nose too deep in there, either. **Or else**, you’ll wind up like the senators."

I assume that « *X, sous peine de Y* » means "*failing X, you run the risk of Y*". But I’m not completely sure how to use this  expression.

Perhaps, « *X, quitte à Y* » is an expression that lies at the other end of the spectrum, with the meaning of "*do X, even at the risk of Y*".

> Il faut en savoir plus sur cette affaire, **quitte à** finir comme les sénateurs.
>
> = "We need to dig deeper into this matter, **even if it means** following the same fate as the senators."

Overall, with « *sous peine de* », the focus is on trying to avoid the risk mentioned, whereas « *quitte à* » is more about being willing to take the risk. Am I correct in my assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sous peine" define clearly a risk (a "peine" is like a sentence, a judgement), but a risk that you don't want to take (EX: Restricted aera, do not entrance, "sous peine de" prison sentence).

"Quitte à" is different, it define a risk that you know but you want to take to have X (EX: I want really to finish this game "quitte à" be late at class).

Sorry but without examples I don't know how to explain that

Comment: This is correct. "*Sous peine*" is followed by something you wouldn't want to happen "*we shouldn't know too much, or we could end up like the senators*". "*Quitte à*" is followed by something that you don't necessarily want, but that you're willing to let happen, because the first thing is worth the risk. "*We must know more, even though we could finish like the senators*".

Comment: Writing that helped me clear it out : Both are risks (not wanted, and have a chance of happening), but the difference is if the first thing is **worth** the risk or not.

Comment: So...yeah, I should have read the whole question, you answered it yourself... Yes, your assumption is perfectly correct.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oh, thank you for confirming my thoughts.